# React and Typescript does't show any error with an un-existing property with a dash "-" in it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

why does typescript not show any error for a React component with an unexisting property with a dash "-" in it?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App</h1>
      <Hello
        something-something={'a'} //Here doesn't show any error even if it is a propery that doens't exist
        name={'World'}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Hello({ name }: { name: string }) {
  return <p>Hello {name}</p>;
}
```

While the same is true for other properties, like `nam` for example?

```
<Hello nam={'World'}  />
```

Ref of the dummy code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mg6zgg?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been brought up already at [ms/TS#32447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32447). This is the **intended behavior** because of `data-` and `aria-` properties (which personally, doesn't make sense to me).

Various fixes and alternatives have been proposed, including:

- A separate compiler option to error on properties using dashes
- Hardcoding allowing only `data-` and `aria-` properties to have dashes
- Only allowing properties with dashes in them in intrinsic elements (p, h1, etc)

However, none of these seem to have been implemented yet.

---

The reason why TypeScript correctly errors on invalid properties such as in your example,

```
<Hello nam={'World'}  />
```

is simply because it doesn't have a dash. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯